# how to read a specific text file in pandas

Tags: text, row

I want to read a specific line in a csv file in pandas on python.
Here is the structure of the file :

file :

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9RadL.png)

how would be the best way to fill the values into a dataframe, with the correct name of the parameters?
thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

**Possible methods:**

1. `pandas.read_table` method seems to be a good way to read (also in chunks) a tabular data file

   - **doc:** https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_table.html
2. pandas has a good fast (compiled) csv reader `pandas.read_csv` (may be more than one).

   - **doc:** https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

**Ref Link:** https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/152194/reading-from-a-txt-file-to-a-pandas-dataframe